# Classic ASP file list

Tags: asp-classic

I have inherited a classic asp application that had over 800 files in the WEBS folder.  Within the directory structure, there are many temp folders that the previous developer(s) made for whatever reason.  I am looking for a way to determine what actual files are relevant to this website/application.

Any ideas out there?? That is without going through every file & tracing everything, hopefully, down!!!

AHIA,
LarryR...

Comment: I am Liking this question in 2017 :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at trying a tool like [ASP Code Analyzer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/AspCodeAnalyzer.aspx). The tool claims that;

> The goal of this tool is to check an ASP project/folder for unused code elements. These elements include unused constants, global variables, functions, subs, and local variables. This comes in very handy if you undertake large changes in a project, or use include files from previous ASP projects and want to be sure, that you do not deploy unnecessary code.